# How to split numbers into 0, int and doubles when parsing in a tokenizer?

Tags: c++, numbers, int, double, tokenize

I'm writing a tokenizer (c++) and want to have a single function to read integers, doubles (which include '.', '+' and 'e' as identifiers) and return multiple 0's as individual 0's.

I've written the code below using some logic that I wrote for identifiers and keywords, but I think I'm missing something or the logic is wrong somewhere.

I'm also not sure if there is a way to do something like
"ch.nextch() == something" (which the function nextch() being the way each character is read). I did a lot of OOP in Java and was able to reference things like student.next() for example but I don't have much experience with c++.

```
static Token parse_number()
{
    string spelling = "" ;

    // append digits to spelling until we read past the end of the integer
    do
    {
        spelling += ch ;
        nextch() ;
    } while ( isdigit(ch)) ;
        if( ch == '0' && ch.next() != '.')
        {
            return new_token(tk_integer, "0" + '\n', line_num, column_num) ;
            nextch() ;
        }
        if( ch == '0' && ch.nextch() == '.' || ch.nextch() == 'e' || ch.nextch() =='E' || ch.nextch() == '+')
        {
            spelling += ch;
            return new_token(tk_double, spelling, line_num, start_column) ;
        }

    // return a new Token object
    return new_token(tk_integer,spelling, line_num, start_column) ;
}
```

Expected output (which I'm not getting because it doesn't recognise doubles or splits the multiple 0):

> {kind: double, spelling: "4.3", line: 1, column: 4}
>
> {kind: double, spelling: "3.6e-89", line: 1, column: 8}
>
> {kind: double, spelling: "12125.34e+9", line: 1, column: 16}
>
> {kind: double, spelling: "888e+0", line: 1, column: 27}
>
> {kind: integer, spelling: "34", line: 1, column: 33}
>
> {kind: integer, spelling: "0", line: 1, column: 36}
>
> {kind: double, spelling: "0.000000e-00008", line: 1, column: 38}

Other non-editable but called functions:

```
typedef int Token ;

enum TokenKind ;
   tk_number,          // one of tk_integer or tk_double
   tk_integer,         // any integer
   tk_double,          // any floating point number
```

Main function:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
Token token ;
int count = 0 ;

// remember and display each token as it is read
token = next_token() ;
while ( token_kind(token) != tk_eoi )
{
    cout << token_to_string(token) << endl ;
    token = next_token() ;
    count++ ;
}
cout << "read " << count << " tokens" << endl ;

return 0 ;
```

}

Next read function:

```
 static void nextch()
{
    extern int read_char() ;

    if ( ch == EOF ) return ;

    if ( ch == '\n' )           // if last ch was newline ...
    {
        line_num++ ;            // increment line number
        column_num = 0 ;        // reset column number
    }

    if ( ch == '\t')
    {
        count++ ;
        column_num = 8 * count ;
    }

    ch = getchar() ;            // read the next character from stdin
    column_num++ ;              // increment the column number
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.  If you can make your problem as simple as possible while still creating the failure, it will help us isolate the issues that will make your code work correctly.  By providing a main() function, it saves time for the person trying to duplicate your error and help you.

Comment: I see no definition for ch, ch.next(), or nextch().  Please provide a complete [mcve]

Comment: I'm addition to the above what makes you think that your logic is wrong? Do you get incorrect results? The `nextch`after the first `return` never gets called.

Comment: @AlanBirtles the code doesn't compile as it doesn't recognise .nextch()

Comment: @Gardener I'll post both in Answers to avoid weird formatting and character limits

Comment: Please post the ch and Token structures/classes.

Comment: @Gardener I’ve now edited the question with the functions you requested (I think)

Comment: It is not possible to copy and paste your code and compile.  It is certainly possible for me to write the code to make that happen, but that is what we ask you to do.  Most of the members here are very smart and can spot bugs without using a compiler.  I am not one of those.  I always pull out my compiler and run gdb on the code to make sure I am understanding the issues.  I cannot do that without writing code, which I do not have time to do right now.  Sorry.

Comment: @Gardener I just didn't know if you had seen I had posted the code since I (stupidly) posted it as an Answer that was later deleted :)

Comment: I see that you changed the post, but there are no #include statements,so it cannot compile :-) .  Copy and paste your code and make sure it compiles.  Then, it will be easier for members to help you.

Comment: You should use std::regex. It is designed for exactly that purpose. With std::sregex_token_iterator you can read a whole line and parse it easily. With one line of code.